# Appium on Node JS - The Appium server is stopped to send requests to the Android emulator after it opened the Chrome browser

Tags: node.js, automation, webdriver, protractor, appium

I've tried to run protractor test scripts(Node JS) on Android emulator by Appium,

but after it opens the Chrome browser in the emulator it stopped to send requests and nothing happen.

no errors on every server (you can see in the attached screenshot below):

[image: This is the actual situation - no errors but nothing happen]

**Protractor conf:**

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require("fs");
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

  specs: ['appiumTest.js'],

  capabilities: {
       browserName: 'chrome',
       browserVersion: '42.0.2311',
     'appium-version': '1.4.1',
     platformName: 'Android',
     platformVersion: '4.4.2',
     deviceName: 'LatestAndroid',
},

  framework: "jasmine",

  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

  getPageTimeout: 30000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      onComplete: function () {},
      // If true, display spec names.
      isVerbose: true,
      // If true, print colors to the terminal.
      showColors: true,
      // If true, include stack traces in failures.
      includeStackTrace: true,
      // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 9999999
  }

};
```

** The test case (sample from github):**

```
"use strict";

require("./helpers/setup");

var wd = require("wd"),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    serverConfigs = require('./helpers/appium-servers');

describe("android webview", function () {
  this.timeout(300000);
  var driver;
  var allPassed = true;

  before(function () {
    var serverConfig = process.env.SAUCE ?
      serverConfigs.sauce : serverConfigs.local;
    driver = wd.promiseChainRemote(serverConfig);
    require("./helpers/logging").configure(driver);

    var desired = process.env.SAUCE ?
      _.clone(require("./helpers/caps").android18) :
      _.clone(require("./helpers/caps").android19);
    desired.app = require("./helpers/apps").selendroidTestApp;
    if (process.env.SAUCE) {
      desired.name = 'android - webview';
      desired.tags = ['sample'];
    }
    return driver
      .init(desired)
      .setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000);
  });

  after(function () {
    return driver
      .quit()
      .finally(function () {
        if (process.env.SAUCE) {
          return driver.sauceJobStatus(allPassed);
        }
      });
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    allPassed = allPassed && this.currentTest.state === 'passed';
  });

  it("should switch to webview", function () {
    return driver
      .elementByName('buttonStartWebviewCD')
        .click()
      .sleep(5000)
      .contexts()
      .then(function (ctxs) {
        console.log(ctxs);
        return driver.context(ctxs[ctxs.length - 1]);
      })
      .elementById('name_input')
        .clear()
        .sendKeys('Appium User')
        .sendKeys(wd.SPECIAL_KEYS.Return)
      .sleep(1000)
      .source().then(function (source) {
        source.should.include('This is my way of saying hello');
        source.should.include('Appium User');
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: can you share the server log to see what exactly is the error.